# There exists a polynomial $p(x)$ in $\mathbb Z_6[x]$ of degree $n$ with more than $n$ distinct zeros

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that this is false over Fields. I'm stumped on how to prove it for non fields.

Answer (score 3):

How many zeros does $p(x)=3x$ have in $\mathbb{Z}_6$?

Comment: In fact, $60\,\%$ of all degree-one polynomials have two roots, so it's hard not to stumble over one by trial and error. If one tries only monic polynomials, however, one needs to try quadratics at least ...

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen: I like the image of stumbling over the roots...it's like walking through an old-growth forest and tripping over the (literal) roots.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** First, this can't work for $n>5$ since there are only six possible zeroes. So look for a smaller degree. You want an integral polynomial $p(x)$ which takes values divisible by $6$. Try starting by including a factor $x, p(x)=x q(x)$. Then when $x$ is even $p$ will be even and when $x$ is divisible by $3$ so will $p$ be. In case $x$ is odd, maybe we should add a factor of $x-1$, $p(x)=x(x-1) r(x)$. Now $p$ is always divisible by $2$, but maybe not by $3$. Can you finish up by choosing a good $r$?

Comment: No, i'm still confused, What even x? You mean the degree of x is even?

Comment: No. I mean if you plug in an even number for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

$6=2\cdot 3$ so $(x+2)(x+3)$ has at least three roots, $-2 \equiv 4$, $-3\equiv 3$, and $0$.